# What is meant by: "She has too many feet and hands"?

Tags: meaning

**What is the meaning of: *She has too many feet and hands?***

Context:
"A tall, awkward girl in a back seat, who seemed to
have too many feet and hands"

Comment: As it stands it suggests he has more than two feet and more than two hands. In what context did you encounter it?

Comment: Can you give more context? Where did you see this? Give the whole paragraph. As it stands, this is not a set phrase or idiom in English or even a proverb.

Comment: The context is required because this *could* be literally referring to someone with extra appendages, someone gawky and awkward who doesn't know what to do with their hands and feet, or you mght say that as a compliment about a goalie.

Comment: Here is the context: A tall,
awkward girl in a back seat, who seemed to
have too many feet and hands.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it from the beginning!

Comment: What book is this from?

Comment: @Mitch Anne of Avonlea.

Comment: Can you give the full paragraph before hand? This could mean a lot of things.

Answer (score 2):

The expression "too many hands and feet" means that someone or something is awkward or self-conscious. Here it appears in [an elocution guide from 1920](https://books.google.com/books?id=XxA5AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA71&lpg=PA71&dq=%22He%20has%20too%20many%20hands%20and%20feet?%22&source=bl&ots=V6FmqUR8d7&sig=ACfU3U31o2r8uJ4T1tYIJUv4HVBY0n0uxA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj4_4bc3vrgAhUKhOAKHWm3DVwQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22He%20has%20too%20many%20hands%20and%20feet%3F%22&f=false):

> So very often it is revealed that a boy who talks or reads indirectly, monotonously, and raucously, can be got to read or talk freely, easily, and pleasantly when induced by some means or other to overlook the fact that people are looking at him or that he **has too many hands and feet** and that he is for the most part a good deal of a gawk and a clown.

That said, while this isn't a common expression, I have found enough examples that this expression has a life of its own in its reference to social or speech anxiety. Here are a couple of more results.

William Archer, in the book *[Poets of the Younger Generation](https://books.google.com/books?id=jpdYAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA278&lpg=PA278&dq=%22too%20many%20hands%20and%20feet%22&source=bl&ots=g8sTELgssu&sig=ACfU3U3HSWsmXkx8yOeqqQB6jnsd41ygPg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiSr97C4PrgAhXqYt8KHeacD4MQ6AEwBnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22too%20many%20hands%20and%20feet%22&f=false)* (1902), uses the phrase "too many hands and feet" to describe a poem made awkward by too much symbolically going on. In particular, the hands in the poem have to carry *so much* (no metrical comments appear here):

> Here we have too much sun and moon and **too many hands and feet**.

And in an article in *[The Book Buyer](https://books.google.com/books?id=SkcDAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA301&lpg=PA301&dq=%22too%20many%20hands%20and%20feet%22&source=bl&ots=C8xJpkS-FG&sig=ACfU3U0ixuVFD2P4v6eA3fbLe4Bsx4e0uw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiSr97C4PrgAhXqYt8KHeacD4MQ6AEwCXoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22too%20many%20hands%20and%20feet%22&f=false)* (1902) the phrase again appears to refer to awkwardness on the part of a character who is described as heroic but ends up speaking or acting clumsily:

> We don't want an author to tell us at the first what a grand and truly noble man the hero is, how finished and cultured and how superlative in every degree, and then to consider his work done; to desert the poor fellow and let him wander clear through the book **with too many hands and feet** and an always unready tongue.

Here is an entry in *[The Saturday Evening Post](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Saturday_Evening_Post/t3phmU8s2-oC?hl=en&gbpv=1)*, February 1, 1919, p. 11, where having "too many hands and feet" seems associated with being tongue-tied or nonverbally anxious in a crowd:

> A girl has about as much use for a tongue-tied shy man as she has for a secondhand typhoid germ or a last year's fashion plate. Especially if he's cursed with **too many hands and feet** - the way I always am when I get into a crowd like this.

Here is a bit from L.M. Montgomery's novel *[Emily's Quest](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Emily_Starr_Series_All_Three_Novels/0MA2DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1)* (1927) (she also wrote *Anne of Green Gables*), which refers to a man having less self-consciousness in social circles:

> He had even acquired certain fundamental rules of social etiquette and learned not to have **too many hands and feet**.

Here's a bit on cheaters in the *[Metropolitan](https://books.google.com/books?id=ABU7AAAAMAAJ&q=%22too%20many%20hands%20and%20feet%22&dq=%22too%20many%20hands%20and%20feet%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjs3v-f6_rgAhXtT98KHdEiCpEQ6AEwBXoECAIQAg)* (1935), p. 358, corresponding with certain tells. (My guess: the person is looking at their hands and feet a lot, as if counting them.):

> Further, the cheater is restless, uneasy, fears detection and usually has **too many hands and feet**.

Finally, lest this expression seem merely a relic of the early 20th century, here's a reviewer from 2011 [describing Juliet in an all-male production of *Romeo and Juliet*](https://www.playshakespeare.com/romeo-and-juliet-reviews/theatre-reviews/3678-romeo-and-juliet-on-a-gender-bender):

> When we meet Juliet, she seems caught right on the cusp between ugly duckling and swanhood. She has bee-stung lips, a deep but not unpleasant voice, and **far too many hands and feet**.

Comment: When I search Google Books for ["has too many hands and feet"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22has+too+many+hands+and+feet%22) I get just 9 hits - at least a couple of which are actually literal "congenital deformity" contexts, and most of the rest are repetitions of a single original 1920 usage. I further suspect your William Archer reference might include a pun of prosody / "metric feet". So I don't think you could meaningfully say this is any kind of "idiom" that's in any sense survived. It's just a "repeatable" mangling of the far more common ***[He's] all arms and feet***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was careful to avoid the word "idiom" for that reason. It's certainly a recognizable or interpretable expression, whatever its origin (which I can't prove). That said, you perhaps found too few results by including a verb: "too many hands and feet" gets over 200 results on Google Books, and more results in other places.

Comment: Mea culpa - I didn't realize that the first page of results inflated how many there actually are. Google Books returns 18 results for the expression "too many hands and feet."

Comment: To the extent there's any "standard" expression here at all, surely it's *arms + legs*, not *hands + feet*. Per my own answer, the counts I got from Google Books were restricted to a specific subject and verb *(**He's / He is all arms and legs**)*, but your point about inaccurate "guestimates" on the first page is well made. Yesterday GB claimed 183 hits for the non-contracted version; today that's gone down to 137, and if I scroll to the second page it admits there are actually only 15. But the contracted (natural) version stabilizes at 176 after scrolling through several pages.

Comment: ...and if we we're playing the numbers game, a search for ***too many hands and feet*** (no subject, no verb) drops to 20 hits after scrolling to the second page. But ***all arms and legs*** starts off claiming **11,500** hits, and Google Books doesn't change its mind about that one even after scrolling through half-a-dozen pages. In terms of *actual usage / currency*, the bottom line is *hands + feet* is effectively "non-existent" compared to *arms + legs*, regardless of whether they're ***all*** or ***too many***.

Comment: I'm not convinced that "too many hands and feet" is a recasting of "all arms and legs." You're appealing to quantity, but I'm not claiming that "too many hands and feet" was especially common. I'm suggesting there are enough results that it stands alone as an expression. I focused on "hands and feet" because it's closest to the expression asked about in the question. On the other hand, while it seems sensible to mention other body idioms, and yours is similar, it's not clear *how* it's related to the questioner's request or this form.

Comment: Without more evidence, it's hard to say much. For instance, these expressions both feel beholden to an oral history we don't have access to.

Comment: Hardly! The first Google Books search cited in my answer very deliberately included the ***contracted*** verb form, maximizing the extent to which results would reflect actual spoken "language", rather than formal written "text". Whatever - I've said my piece, and I shall let the numbers speak for themselves hereafter.

Comment: I wasn't saying that the printed examples don't reflect a spoken context, but only that there may be many spoken examples that were never printed, including ones that might explain the origin of these expressions. At present, the numbers don't provide any explanation of origin or relation.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin I guess you're right. Thanks a lot. Here is the context just to be sure: "A tall,
awkward girl in a back seat, who seemed to
have too many feet and hands."

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a slightly clunky recasting of...

> [***He's all arms and legs***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he%27s+all+arms+and+legs%22) (241 hits in Google Books, plus [183 non-contracted instances](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+is+all+arms+and+legs%22))
>    *skinny and gawky-looking, often with overtones of "clumsy"* (***my*** definition)

While searching for a slang dictionary definition of this term (which I'm quite familiar with in the sense given above), I came across this "new-to-me" definition...

> *All arms and legs is slang for weak beer* ([lingomash.com](https://lingomash.com/slang-meanings/232/slang-meaning-of-all-arms-and-legs))

I must admit have no idea how that second definition arose, or how common it is.

---

EDIT: - pretty obvious in retrospect, I guess...

> ***All arms and legs*** - [*I Never Knew There Was a Word For It* (2005)](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ItYq7wYG634C&pg=PT507&lpg=PT507&dq=All%20arms%20and%20legs%20is%20slang%20for%20weak%20beer%20%22no%20body%22&source=bl&ots=F_l3qIzHK7&sig=ACfU3U1kz31K9jEpuhKEQTxe2GhigAHnmw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjWyvCm-vzgAhWtsaQKHRdWAV4Q6AEwAXoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=All%20arms%20and%20legs%20is%20slang%20for%20weak%20beer%20%22no%20body%22&f=false)
>    UK slang 19C
>   **weak beer** (i.e. a drink that has **no body**)

Comment: The username for this answer checks out. ;) Here's an example of the first meaning in Patricia Highsmith's book [Small g](https://books.google.com/books?id=mzWqhk_ApgEC&pg=PA131&lpg=PA131&dq=%22all+arms+and+legs%22+beer&source=bl&ots=_z1K8a104O&sig=ACfU3U0W-o0Uck1_-ysWR4CaooUkaXEJLw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwixv4j93frgAhUQNd8KHQaSDf4Q6AEwAHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22all%20arms%20and%20legs%22%20beer&f=false) (If you can tell by the search terms, I couldn't find the second version attested.)

Comment: **All arms and legs is slang for weak beer**. Probably beacause the beer "is all arms and legs but has no _body_". This used to be a common complaint regarding inferior beer and meant that it was weak, watery and tasteless as opposed to beer with lots of _body_ like porter, particularly Guinness.

Comment: Also _two left feet_ and _all thumbs_. An excess of one limb to the detriment of the others seems to be a very common way of expressing clumsiness.